# Переход на Java 8 или выше -- intelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx, java-8, java-7

Всех приветствую! Появилась ещё проблема, в проекте с использованием библиотеки libGDX не работает то, что я делал в тестовом проекте, что вполне логично так как версия была - 7, я нигде не могу найти как реально поменять версию. Я попытался поменять версию, но ничего не изменилось. Опять извиняюсь если это дубликат какого-то вопроса, но я вроде точно таких же -- не нашел.

**Вот такая ошибка:**

[image: Ошибка и строчка кода:]

**После я попытался изменить версию в File - Project Structure - Modules и Project.**

[image: Modules :]

**И также:**
[image: Project Structure]

Ошибка осталась, может кто, знает -- в чём проблема то? *За ранее спасибо всем!*

Comment: А в гредле какая версия прописана?

Comment: Это в файлах build.grandle -> 
sourceCompatibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В IDE выбран уровень Java 17, поэтому весь код из более ранних версий должен поддерживаться.

Скорее всего, где-то во вложенных `build.gradle` файлах, которые относятся к LibGDX, прописана совместимость с JDK 1.7, поэтому следует проверить все такие файлы на наличие строки вида:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
```

где и нужно будет установить уровень 1.8.

Похожий вопрос на основном SO: [How to change Java version of libgdx project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72420069/how-to-change-java-version-of-libgdx-project)

Comment: Я почему-то думал, что уже менял там. Хм, ну вроде после изменения оно заработало, хотя и пришлось чуть-чуть поменять код в других местах. Спасибо. А также спасибо @mesfex